# What is the correct suffix for someone or something from "Bonaire"?

Tags: word-choice

Living on the island of Bonaire, a question has arisen on the correct suffix to be used when describing someone from, or an item pertaining to, the island of Bonaire. Both "Bonairian" and "Bonairean" seem to be in use. Which is correct, and what is the grammar rule that defines it?

Comment: Wouldn't these be pronounced the same way? So it's just a variant spelling.

Comment: They are pronounced the same way. My question is which is the more accurate spelling in written documents.

Comment: There is no grammar rule that defines it.  It really comes down to what these people choose to call themselves.

Comment: Ask the other locals. Such names are historical. There is no special rule for concocting them.

Comment: I don't know what the adjective *is*, but I know it should be "de bonaire"

Comment: Interesting misplaced modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than following a rule, the choice of suffix here is a matter of opinion, so [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bonairian%2CBonairean&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBonairian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBonairean%3B%2Cc0) might be helpful:

[image]

Seems like *Bonairean* is about twice as popular, ([106](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bonairean%22#q=%22bonairean%22&start=100&tbm=bks) citations vs [57](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bonairian%22#q=%22bonairian%22&start=70&tbm=bks)), but simply googling the web turns up [250](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bonairean%22#q=%22bonairean%22&start=250) vs. [316](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bonairian%22#q=%22bonairian%22&start=319), which seems to indicate relative equality. No doubt you would find faithful advocates on either side.

[Info Bonaire](http://www.infobonaire.com/), the most official website that I could find about Bonaire, sides with *Bonairean*.

Answer (score 0):

[Google fight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=Bonairian&word2=Bonairean) shows *Bonairean* is more common than *Bonairian* ( 2910 vs 389 results) but still on a very low base of numbers.

[Bonaire Wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonaire#Economy) : It is curious that in the article about Bonaire they never use   Bonairean or Bonairian  when they refer, for instance, to Bonaire's  economy ,  Bonair's airport or Bonaire's educational system. It appears that both  adjectives are rarely used.

Comment: Isn't there a Bonarian linguistics czar to pronounce on the matter? Perhaps they could then go on to help Westward Ho! out.

Comment: I wonder why Google fight comes up with such a different number than actually googling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm native of Bonaire and facing the same thing. I did a quick scan. Some people sent me a message coorecting me. "Bonaire - Bonairean"